# How to get the total working days for each month based on employee setting on database in mongdb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

This is the database setting for working schedule of an employee.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a9797b480591678e0771190"), 
    "staff_id" : NumberInt(172), 
    "temp_name" : "Regular Employment", 
    "individual_setting" : false, 
    "employment_category" : "Regular Employee", 
    "branch_office" : "Cebu Branch Office", 
    "availability_status" : "Incumbent", 
    "req_working_hours" : "08:00", 
    "fixed_brk_time_from" : "12:00", 
    "fixed_brk_time_to" : "13:00", 
    "sch_time_setting" : [
        {
            "holiday" : [
                "Saturday", 
                "Friday"
            ], 
            "biweekly_odd" : [

            ], 
            "biweekly_even" : [
                "Saturday"
            ], 
            "clock_in_mon" : "08:40", 
            "clock_in_tue" : "08:40", 
            "clock_in_wed" : "08:40", 
            "clock_in_thu" : "08:40", 
            "clock_in_fri" : "08:40", 
            "clock_in_sat" : "08:40", 
            "clock_in_sun" : null, 
            "clock_in_hol" : null, 
            "clock_out_mon" : "18:00", 
            "clock_out_tue" : "18:00", 
            "clock_out_wed" : "18:00", 
            "clock_out_thu" : "18:00", 
            "clock_out_fri" : "18:00", 
            "clock_out_sat" : "18:00", 
            "clock_out_sun" : null, 
            "clock_out_hol" : null, 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a9797b480591678e077118f")
        }
    ], 
    "date_to_start" : ISODate("2018-03-01T06:03:32.050+0000"), 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-03-01T06:03:32.066+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-03-01T06:03:32.066+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

And I want to know how many working days should be for him for this month.

And since each employee has different schedule, so I count first how many clock-in field in his setting:

```
async.parallel({
st_setting: function(callback) {
            Ie_setting.aggregate([
                {
                    $project: {
                        day_of_week: {
                          $map: {
                               input: "$sch_time_setting",
                               as: "setting",
                               in: {
                                  _id: "$$setting._id",
                                  kvPairs: {
                                    $objectToArray: "$$setting"
                                  }
                               }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        day_of_week: {
                            $map: {
                               input: "$day_of_week",
                               as: "clockIn",
                               in: {
                                  _id: "$$clockIn._id",
                                  count: { 
                                    $size: { $filter: { input: "$$clockIn.kvPairs", as: "pair", cond: { $and: [
                                    {$eq: [{ $indexOfBytes: [ "$$pair.k", "clock_in_" ] },0]},{$ne: ["$$pair.v",null]}] } } } }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]).exec(callback);
        },
    }, function(err, results) {
    res.json({data: results});
});
```

And the result is:

```
"st_setting": [
            {
                "_id": "5a9797b480591678e0771190",
                "day_of_week": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5a9797b480591678e077118f",
                        "count": 6
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
```

So there is 6 days expected for each week.
Sometimes an employee has work schedule during weekends.

So how do I know how many working days for this month (let's say, February 2018).

I tried to search javascript code on how to get total working days for each month but won't worked on my case. Since schedule is different.

Comment: There is a library call `Moment.js`, and you might want to take a look at https://momentjs.com/